# If C is a chain of non-principal ideals and the union of the ideals of the chain contains a generator, why is the union then principal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

If C is a chain of non-principal ideals and the union of the ideals of the chain contains a generator why is the union then principal. I understand this is a contradiction already and seems painfully obvious but its not clicking for me at the moment.

Say S is a set of non-principal ideals and $\{C_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a chain in S. and say theres a generator $d$ in some ideal $C_k$. Why is $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i = \langle d \rangle$ ?

Comment: A generator of what?  If an ideal has a generator, it's principal by definition.

Comment: @Slade im trying to understand the contradiction more thoroughly. initially stating the set has no principal ideals. then saying theres an element in one of the ideals such that it will generate a principal ideal. Why does the union of all those ideals then become principal?

Comment: Any element generates a principal ideal.  You need to be more specific about what you're trying to show, or what reference you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outwardly, one might guess you are working with Zorn's lemma on the poset of non-principal ideals.

Suppose for a moment that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i$ is not in the poset: then it must be principal. But if $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i = ( d )$, then $d\in C_i$ for some $i$, and then $C_i\subseteq (d)\subseteq C_i$, so that we have equality and that $C_i$ is principal, a contradiction.

The upshot of this is that the union cannot be principal, and so the chain has an upper bound in the poset. That is, Zorn's lemma applies to the poset.

You appear to be transposing the assumption (that the union is principal) and the conclusion (that $d$ lies in one of the links in the chain) of this argument. This is possibly why you feel confused.